# Round text labels of ggplot2 to closest thousand and skip zeros

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below

```
d1_1<-structure(list(conm = c("Amazon.com Inc", "Apple Inc", "Facebook Inc", 
"Intl Business Machines Corp", "Microsoft Corp", "Netflix Inc", 
"Paypal Holdings Inc", "Qualcomm Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Twitter Inc"
), avg_profit = c(12613.1818181818, 62428.7272727273, 14952.8181818182, 
20280.8181818182, 40535.5833333333, 1145.86854545455, 2810.25, 
6653.63636363636, 705.462090909091, 189.0503)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and I want to round the text labels of the bars to the closes thousand like the image below.

[image]

I do

```
roundUp <- function(x) 10^ceiling(log10(x))
```

and

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=d1_1, aes(x=avg_profit, y=reorder(conm,avg_profit))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  ylab("Company") + xlab("Average profit in $millions")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Average profit in $millions", labels=scales::dollar_format())+
  geom_text(aes(label=roundUp(avg_profit)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust=-0.2,size=3)
p
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? What's wrong with the code you've got?

Comment: You can round to nearest thousands like this `round(x, -3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label=round(avg_profit, -3)/1000
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data = d1_1, aes(x = avg_profit, y = reorder(conm, avg_profit))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Company") + xlab("Average profit in $millions") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Average profit in $millions", labels = scales::dollar_format()) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(avg_profit, -3)/1000),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    hjust = -0.2,
    size = 3)
```